# Mocking and unmocking named imports using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, es6-modules

I've been reading about this in the [official documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks), in [this blogpost](https://medium.com/codeclan/mocking-es-and-commonjs-modules-with-jest-mock-37bbb552da43), and [this issue in jest repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936). Neither the documentation or the blogpost cover the scenario I'm trying to test. The issue thread does cover it, but I can't get the tests to pass using any of the solutions proposed there.

Can you complete the following code to make the tests pass?

> **Edit**: To be clearer, I want to know how to mock the imported functions in a way that I can still use the original implementation in some tests and the mock in others.
>
> These `foo` and `bar` functions may seem very simple and a small change in the implementation could make the tests pass, but the question that I have is about mocking.
>
> For a bit more context I'm actually trying to test two sagas defined in the same file that have side effects that I don't want to run. I still want to unit test each of those sagas separately

```js
// a.js
export const foo = () => 'foo-' + bar()
export const bar = () => 'bar'
```

```js
// a.test.js
import {
  foo,
  bar
} from './a'

describe('foo', () => {
  it('should return foo-MOCKED_BAR', () => {
    expect(foo()).toBe('foo-MOCKED_BAR')
  })

  it('should have the mocked implementation of bar', () => {
    expect(bar()).toBe('MOCKED_BAR')
  })
})

describe('bar', () => {
  it('should have the original implementation of bar', () => {
    expect(bar()).toBe('bar')
  })
})

describe('foo and bar together', () => {
  it('should have the original implementation of both', () => {
    expect(foo()).toBe('foo-bar')
  })
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i dont really use the framework but this should work

```js
//a.js
export const foo = (arg) => 'foo-' + bar(arg)
export const bar = (arg) => arg ? 'bar' : 'MOCKED_BAR'

//a.test.js
describe('foo', () => {
  it('should return foo-MOCKED_BAR', () => {
    expect(foo(0)).toBe('foo-MOCKED_BAR')
  })

  it('should have the mocked implementation of bar', () => {
    expect(bar(1)).toBe('MOCKED_BAR')
  })
})

describe('bar', () => {
  it('should have the original implementation of bar', () => {
    expect(bar(1)).toBe('bar')
  })
})

describe('foo and bar together', () => {
  it('should have the original implementation of both', () => {
    expect(foo(1)).toBe('foo-bar')
  })
})
```

Comment: You're right in that tests would pass with your changes. However, my intention was to know how to mock the different imported methods so the actual implementation was not called. I'll edit the question to be more clear about it